# Navigating JSON OBJ PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to navigate this object, for example, getting where the query was successful? Then how would could I echo a list of the item's images? How would I go about doing that? Here is the object:

```
{"assets":[{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629782983591116717","classid":"2225518126","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629782983591116718","classid":"2225518127","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629782983591116719","classid":"2225518128","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629782983591116720","classid":"2225518129","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629782983591116721","classid":"2225518130","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629782983591116722","classid":"2225518131","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"629784346414177276","classid":"2225519077","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"},{"appid":"578080","contextid":"2","assetid":"1489972504775585911","classid":"2225519336","instanceid":"0","amount":"1"}],"descriptions":[{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225518126","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh23qr2q44kS6_hSs5hYQ","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh23qr2q44kS6_hSs5hYQ","descriptions":[{"type":"bbcode","value":"Basic costume. Unable to sell."}],"tradable":0,"name":"T-shirt (White)","type":"","market_name":"T-shirt (White)","market_hash_name":"T-shirt (White)","commodity":1,"marketable":0},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225518127","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh23qr2qI4kS6_5VSGhhQ","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh23qr2qI4kS6_5VSGhhQ","descriptions":[{"type":"bbcode","value":"Basic costume. Unable to sell."}],"tradable":0,"name":"T-shirt (GREY)","type":"","market_name":"T-shirt (GREY)","market_hash_name":"T-shirt (GREY)","commodity":1,"marketable":0},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225518128","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh13qr2q44kS6_JqUnfyw","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh13qr2q44kS6_JqUnfyw","descriptions":[{"type":"bbcode","value":"Basic costume. Unable to sell."}],"tradable":0,"name":"Combat Pants (khaki)","type":"","market_name":"Combat Pants (khaki)","market_hash_name":"Combat Pants (khaki)","commodity":1,"marketable":0},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225518129","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh13qr2qI4kS68j7cB83g","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh13qr2qI4kS68j7cB83g","descriptions":[{"type":"bbcode","value":"Basic costume. Unable to sell."}],"tradable":0,"name":"Combat Pants (Brown)","type":"","market_name":"Combat Pants (Brown)","market_hash_name":"Combat Pants (Brown)","commodity":1,"marketable":0},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225518130","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh03qr2qI4kS69PNyQIbw","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh03qr2qI4kS69PNyQIbw","descriptions":[{"type":"bbcode","value":"Basic costume. Unable to sell."}],"tradable":0,"name":"Hi-top Trainers","type":"","market_name":"Hi-top Trainers","market_hash_name":"Hi-top Trainers","commodity":1,"marketable":0},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225518131","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh-3qr2q44kS68j8j0hXw","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQurmh-3qr2q44kS68j8j0hXw","descriptions":[{"type":"bbcode","value":"Basic costume. Unable to sell."}],"tradable":0,"name":"Utility Belt","type":"","market_name":"Utility Belt","market_hash_name":"Utility Belt","commodity":1,"marketable":0},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225519077","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQtrmh13qr2qI4kS68cmV5sDA","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQtrmh13qr2qI4kS68cmV5sDA","tradable":1,"name":"Combat Pants (Grey Camo)","type":"","market_name":"Combat Pants (Grey Camo)","market_hash_name":"Combat Pants (Grey Camo)","commodity":1,"market_tradable_restriction":7,"market_marketable_restriction":7,"marketable":1},{"appid":578080,"classid":"2225519336","instanceid":"0","currency":0,"background_color":"","icon_url":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQtrmhw3qr2qI4kS6_fzXn7Yg","icon_url_large":"8HAGSsiI9OXk0bu4o76O6xabNUY8RRLf00e56zWT3IZUH8Flab9goIFna_837oFuZVQtrmhw3qr2qI4kS6_fzXn7Yg","tradable":1,"name":"Gas Mask","type":"","market_name":"Gas Mask","market_hash_name":"Gas Mask","commodity":1,"market_tradable_restriction":7,"market_marketable_restriction":7,"marketable":1}],"total_inventory_count":8,"success":1,"rwgrsn":-2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$test = '{"assets":[{"appid":"578..."rwgrsn":-2}';
$objectTest = json_decode($test);
$arrayTest = json_decode($test, true);

var_dump($objectTest->success);
var_dump($arrayTest['success']);
```

https://3v4l.org/AMmbX#output

Comment: Okay that works but how could I echo a list of item's images?

Comment: try this: `foreach ($arrayTest['descriptions'] as $item) {
    echo $item['icon_url'];
}`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!